# create a temp table with serial/auto increment column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Good Day
I am trying to create a temp table with a auto increment column.  I have tried various versions of the following, but i am not getting it to work.

```
create temp table aatemp1 as (id serial, (select unnest (string_to_array('388c45f-998d-4d9c-b59a-bd37b70bba7a', '-'))));
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  What happens when you try it?  Do you get an error message?  What is the error message?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Sorry - was running off to a meeting.  I get a syntax error        ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `as` should not be there.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html

Comment: @AndyLester: he is trying to do a `create table .. as select ..`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't combine "static" column definitions and a select like that.

You need to do this in two steps:

```
create temp table aatemp1 
(
  id serial, 
  some_value text
);

insert into aatemp1(some_value)
select unnest (string_to_array('388c45f-998d-4d9c-b59a-bd37b70bba7a', '-'));
```

if you just want to have a sequential number in the temp table, you could also do it like this:

```
create temp table aatemp1
as
select row_number() over (order by null) as id, 
       t.*
from (
   select unnest (string_to_array('388c45f-998d-4d9c-b59a-bd37b70bba7a', '-'))
) t;
```

(but that would not generate "new" ids when you insert more rows)

Comment: that did was the trick - I did not think about two parts. Thanks much